# Inkscape working on local machine but not working on docker container

Tags: python, docker

```
FROM python:3.10

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y inkscape

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["gunicorn", "--workers", "8", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8484", "wsgi:app"]
```

The above is my docker file .

The below is my code

```
   image_name = re.sub(r'[^\w\s-]', '', title)
             svgchart  = chart_pygal.render()
             inkscape_process = subprocess.Popen(['inkscape', '-z', '-e', '-', '-'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
             png_data, error = inkscape_process.communicate(input=svgchart)
             png_io = BytesIO(png_data)
             return send_file(png_io ,mimetype='image/png', download_name=image_name+'.png', as_attachment=True)
```

I am doing svg to png conversion and it is working fine on my  machine but not working on docker container.
with the following error : sorry the photos can not open this file because the formate is not supported or the file is currported and the size of image downloaded is 0kb

Comment: Why not use `chart_pygal.render_to_png(…)` ?

Comment: it is not supoorting arabic language